# cy.intercept randomly not work when "delay" is set

Tags: javascript, cypress

I use [cy.intercept](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept) to mock an api.

But I can't understand why the requests are not always intercepted by cy.intercept. The failure is random.

Here is my intercept function

```js
  cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/search?searchValue=**', {fixture: 'searchFixutre.json', delay: 500}).as('api');
```

Randomly, when this route is called several times quickly, Cypress does not intercept the request and it is sent directly to the api server.

Note that this problem does not occur when I delete the "delay" property

```js
cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/search?searchValue=**', {fixture: 'searchFixutre.json'}).as('api');
```

Comment: How is the app sending the API call? With `fetch()` I cannot reproduce the problem - the intercept catches multiple requests consistently.

Comment: Why did you use the delay property in the first place?

Comment: @TesterDick To be honest I try to reproduce this issue on blank project but without success.

Comment: @PhilipAllStar I use delay because I also test skeleton display during API Call delay.